# Capture Image Display it on ImageView and save images in SD card with different serial number

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have added the following code for my camera activity, the code works fine but it only creates one image in the directory.
I want to add more images with sequence image.1.jpg,image.2.jpg and so on.
How should i do this.
Kindly Suggest.

```
public class camera extends AppCompatActivity {
            ImageButton image_button;
            ImageView image_view;
            static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);
                image_button= (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
                image_view= (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
                image_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        File file = getFile();
                        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
                        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
                    }
                });

            }
            private File getFile()
            {
                File folder = new File("sdcard/3D_TRY");
                if (!folder.exists())
                {
                    folder.mkdir();
                }

                File imagefile = new File(folder,"image.jpg");
                return imagefile;
            }
        @Override
            protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                String path = "sdcard/3D_TRY/image.jpg";
                image_view.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(path));
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line

```
File imagefile = new File(folder, "image.jpg");
```

from

```
String imageName = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg";
File imagefile = new File(folder, imageName);
```